# How to throw messages to http response from case class require?

Tags: spray, akka-http, json4s

Given a case class with any require

```
case class Foo(id: Int, value: Int) {
    require(value < 0 "value must be bigger than zero")
}
```

Is possible to throw this messages to http?

```
val routes = pathPrefix("foos") {
    pathEnd {
      post {
        entity(as[Foo]) { foo =>
          saveFoo(foo) match {
            case Success(p) => {
              complete(StatusCodes.Created)
            }
            case Failure(f) => {
              println(f.getMessage) // unknown error
              complete(BadRequest, f.getMessage)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Akka-HTTP infrastructure will already convert all errors occurring during unmarshalling into a `400 (BadRequest)` error, and the exception message will be automatically used.

With your same code I am getting that behaviour for free. Small changes I made:

- the business logic error is now a `500`, to avoid confusion
- the case class requirement is now consistent with the message (`>` is required instead of `<`).

---

```
  case class Foo(id: Int, value: Int) {
    require(value > 0, "value must be bigger than zero")
  }

  def saveFoo(foo: Foo): Try[Unit] = Success(())

  val route = pathPrefix("foos") {
    pathEnd {
      post {
        entity(as[Foo]) { foo =>
          saveFoo(foo) match {
            case Success(p) => {
              complete(StatusCodes.Created)
            }
            case Failure(f) => {
              println(f.getMessage) // unknown error
              complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, f.getMessage)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That is what I thought, too. But the message from f.getMessage is "unknown error"

Comment: That block you where you print `f.getMessage` is evaluated in case your method `saveFoo` returns a Failure. If you are printing `f.getMessage` it means the unmarshalling was fine and the error was later. The rejection of unmarshalling errors with BadRequest happens under the hood , without the need to add any code.